# CNNs on Keras converge to the same value no matter the input

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been learning Keras recently and I tried my hand at the CIFAR10 dataset with CNNs. However, the model I trained (you can run the code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AhYf84GIOnMwKPj6XIbAVo3dOWCmBf8p)) returns the same answer for **every** input, no matter what. Did I forget something in the model definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to normalize the images. Currently, the values in `x_train` are in the range `[0,255]`. This causes large gradient updates and stalls training process. One simple normalization scheme in this case would be:

```py
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255
```

This causes the values to fall in the range `[0,1]`. Then you would surely see that the training progresses.

---

A more sophisticated normalization scheme involves feature-wise (i.e. pixel-wise) normalization or centering. In this approach we normalize all the images such that each pixel in all the images have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one (i.e. they mostly fall in the range `[-1,1]`):

```py
# make sure values are float
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

x_mean = x_train.mean(axis=0)
x_train -= x_mean
x_std = x_train.std(axis=0)
x_train /= x_std + 1e-8  # add a small constant to prevent division by zero

# normalize test data using the mean and std of training data
x_test -= x_mean
x_test /= x_std + 1e-8
```

Note the last part: **NEVER EVER** normalize test data by its own mean and std. Use the training mean and std instead.

Comment: Oh, normalizing the values did the trick. Didn't think it'd be this relevant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are doing prediction on x_test

```
predictions = model.predict_classes(x_test, batch_size=50)
```

and than comparing them with y_train

```
comparison = [(predictions[i], y_train_[i][0]) for i in range(0, len(predictions))]
```

I think it should be y_test

Comment: This is surely true, and I just corrected it, but the two still don't match.

Comment: you have to train for longer epoch or until Loss is dropping. Loss 14 is still to high

Comment: Increasing the number of epochs has no effect: it's like the network converged to a local minimum and won't move from there.